# Set Relationship is not working on sandbox Sugarcrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

This is m logic hook  `After Save` , this logic hook is perfectly working on my local machine.
 But it is not working on sandboxcopy. I asked this question to Sugar Support team , 
They found that **Set_relationship**  is not working .
But my question is why this is working on local or is there any alternate way to write this code, where i am wrong ?

```
class RHLogicHook {

    function ReportingTeam($bean, $event, $arguments) {

        if (isset($arguments['isUpdate']) && $arguments['isUpdate'] == false) {
            $reporting_head = BeanFactory::retrieveBean('Contacts', $bean->contact_id_c);
            $contact = BeanFactory::retrieveBean('Contacts', $bean->contacts_rh_reporting_head_1contacts_ida);

            $reporting_team = new RH_reporing_team();
            $reporting_team->contact_id_c = $contact->id;
            $reporting_team->save();
            $dataset = array(
                'contacts_rh_reporing_team_1contacts_ida' => $reporting_head->id,
                'contacts_rh_reporing_team_1rh_reporing_team_idb' => $reporting_team->id,
            );
            $reporting_team->set_relationship('contacts_rh_reporing_team_1_c', array(), false, false, $dataset);

        }
    }

}
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please dont use above . use load relation and add method .

```
class RHLogicHook {

    function ReportingTeam($bean, $event, $arguments) {

        if (isset($arguments['isUpdate']) && $arguments['isUpdate'] == false) {
            $reporting_head = BeanFactory::retrieveBean('Contacts', $bean->contact_id_c);
            $contact = BeanFactory::retrieveBean('Contacts', $bean->contacts_rh_reporting_head_1contacts_ida);

            $reporting_team = new RH_reporing_team();
            $reporting_team->contact_id_c = $contact->id;
            $reporting_team->save();

            $GLOBALS['log']->log('zob_ms_bean ' . print_r($reporting_head, 1));


            if ( $reporting_head->load_relationship('contacts_rh_reporing_team_1')) {
               $reporting_head->contacts_rh_reporing_team_1->add($reporting_team->id);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how this answer is incorrect i is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

some of the functions are blacklisted, if thats the case you can easily use a trick to make sure that your code works great on production instance.Try below mentioned trick:

$hack_function="set_relationship";
$reporting_team->$hack_function('contacts_rh_reporing_team_1_c', array(), false, false, $dataset);

lets hope this solves your issue.